# Do you need omniauth to work with koala?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, omniauth, koala

I am a rails newbie and I was wondering if you have to have omniauth in order to work with koala. For example, if I followed this sites code, http://udooz.net/blog/2011/02/facebook-app-using-rails-koala/, would I need omniauth already set up to do so?

Answer (score 1):

No.  In that particular example, everything there looks like it should work as is (disclaimer: I have not tried the example myself.)  In general, Koala doesn't require OmniAuth.

What OmniAuth gives you is a single gem to let you easily authenticate users with your choice of third-party authentication systems.  It would be useful if you are considering allowing your users to login with more than just their Facebook credentials, like Twitter or Open ID credentials.

For completeness, here's the source of most of the information of that blog post from the Koala wiki on Github: https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Koala-on-Rails

Answer (score 1):

You don't need OmniAuth.  I've used Koala only.